# Почему не работает код в IE и Firefox?

Tags: html, css, анимация, svg

Почему не работает код в IE и Firefox? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKEvzZ

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.over-ring {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 13px solid #dfe8ed;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.over-image {
  display: inline-block;
  stroke: #30bae7;
  stroke-width: 13px;
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  stroke-dasharray: 465;
  stroke-dashoffset: 49;
  fill: transparent;
  animation: circus 3.7s ease;
  position: absolute;
  top: -423px;
  left: -83px;
}

#bar {
  r: 73.5;
  cx: 150;
  cy: 150;
}

@keyframes circus {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 465
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 49
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-diagramma">
  <div class="over-ring">
    <svg id="svg" class="over-image">
      <circle id="bar"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему он должен работать?

Answer (score 3):

Удалите вот это:

```
#bar {
  r: 73.5;
  cx: 150;
  cy: 150;
}
```

Перенесите эти аттрибуты сюда:

```
<circle  cx="150" cy="150" r="73.5"></circle>
```

После этого заработает FireFox, IE у вас не заработает, потому что IE не поддерживает анимацию CSS у SVG элементов, только Edge